# How to build coreutils with LLVM 3.4

Tags: llvm, gnu-coreutils

I am trying to build GNU Coreutils 8.23 using the LLVM 3.4 tool-chain. One very important aspect is that I also need the LLVM bytecode for all the coreutils. Therefore, I need to include `-emit-llvm` in the CFLAGS. Therefore, I removed the $(CFLAGS) from the LINK variable of the coreutils Makefile. Afterwards, I run the following command:

```
make CC=/home/user/llvm-3.4.2/build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang 
CCLD=/home/user/llvm-3.4.2/build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-link 
IGNORE_UNUSED_LIBRARIES_CFLAGS= CFLAGS="-emit-llvm -S" 
VERBOSE=1 AM_CFLAGS= AM_LDFLAGS= 
AR=/home/user/llvm-3.4.2/build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ar 
RANLIB=/home/user/llvm-3.4.2/build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-ranlib
```

and I get the following error:

```
/home/user/llvm-3.4.2/build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-link: src/libver.a:1:2:    error: expected integer
!<arch>
 ^
/home/user/llvm-3.4.2/build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-link: error loading file 'src/libver.a'
```

Any ideas of how to get this to work?

Comment: Ever tried [wllvm](https://github.com/travitch/whole-program-llvm) to compile it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
export CC="/home/user/llvm-3.4.2/build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang"
export CXX="/home/user/llvm-3.4.2/build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++"
```

Make sure this is where your compiler toolchain is present.

Then in the the `coreutils` directory, run `./configure` (before this run  `./bootstrap` if you havent already run it). Running `./configure` checks if your `clang` can compile properly and creates a `Makefile` with the correct configuration.

Then do a `make` and `make install` as instructed.

Comment: I got a redifinition error of max_align_t typedef variable. I commented it out in coreutils/lib/stddef.h. I was able to build rest of the code with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Lib file '.a' here is not readable by llvm-link.
A possible informal hack to this probably is to find out the Makefile generating this lib, and let

```
AR = llvm-link, ar option = -o(i.e. change ar rv to llvm-link -o),
```

and disable ranlib command while compling(you don't need ranlib if using llvm-link).

Then the '.a' file generated is a stitched bc file, and this '.a' file should be accpetable by llvm-link command you are calling